# Parsing json file in hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I am trying to load the json file in hive.Below is sample json file.

```
{"Result":[
{"Col1":"Key1","Col2":"abc@gmail.com","Col3":"7"},
{"Col1":"Key2","Col2":"abc@gmail.com","Col3":"7"},
{"Col1":"Key3","Col2":"abc@gmail.com","Col3":"7"},
{"Col1":"Key4","Col2":"abc@gmail.com","Col3":"7"}
]}
```

I have tried below create statement in hive.

```
create table if not exists sample_json (A Array<struct<"Col1":String,"Col2":string,"Col3":string>>) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' LOCATION '/a/b/c'
```

I am not able to retrieve the each columns data from table.I have tried to explode the array but it returns only 1st record .Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testJson (
      Result ARRAY <struct<Col1:String ,
                           Col2 : string ,
                           Col3 : string > >)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION 's3n://temp_db.db/testjsonstring';
```

> Query

```
SELECT
        t.col1
        ,t.col2
        ,t.col3
    FROM
        testJson LATERAL VIEW explode (result) r AS t LIMIT 100
```

> Result

```
Col1    Col2          Col3
Key1    abc@gmail.com   7
Key2    abc@gmail.com   7
Key3    abc@gmail.com   7
Key4    abc@gmail.com   7
```

Comment: Thanks @rbyndoor it worked after writting seperate load inpath statement.